# How can I exactly position things I paste to Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have no idea how can I set position of a text/picture that I paste through code in C#.

My code looks like this.

```cs
Word.Application wa = new Word.Application();
wa.Visible = false;
Word.Document wd = wa.Documents.Add(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
Word.Document wf1 = null, wf2 = null;
wf1 = wa.Documents.Open(p3, ref miss, true, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, false);
wf2 = wa.Documents.Open(p4, ref miss, true, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, false);
Word.Range or1 = wf1.Content;
Word.Range or2 = wf2.Content;
File.AppendAllText(p2, Environment.NewLine + textBox1.Text);
string pp = textBox4.Text + " " + textBox5.Text;
string[] kdt = new string[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, pp };
or1.CopyAsPicture();
wa.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault);
or2.CopyAsPicture();
wa.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault);
wa.Selection.EndKey(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdStory);
wa.Selection.TypeText("\n");
wa.Selection.Font.Name = "Arial";
wa.Selection.Font.Bold = 0;
wa.Selection.Font.Size = 11;
wa.Selection.TypeText("\n" + textBox1.Text + "\n" + textBox2.Text + "\n" + textBox3.Text + "\n" + textBox4.Text + " " + textBox5.Text);
wd.SaveAs2(p1);
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

but it looks more like this:

[image]

Any ideas what do i do wrong?

Edit1:Already tried using template document and just paste text i need in there but it always added text like on second screenshot. Now i try to put it all together using word table, still having problem cause i cant find way to paste formated text with picture, maybe i just do something wrong or don't know the right command.

Comment: I'd use a table in the doc with zero border width

Comment: @JPHellemons You mean that i should put all textboxe´s in one table and then paste in?

Comment: You want to insert text on a specific place in a document. In your sample, it looks like a 2 column layout. It looks on this moment like a no column layout. just left and right aligned. Is pasting the right way? Or should you just generate the doc from scratch or use a template? What part on the screenshot represents what textbox?

Comment: Im taking 2 word doc´s, merging them together and then i want to add text. Should i just first put it all in one table and then paste into word? And yes, it has to be new doc file.

Comment: I just have no other idea than copy and paste from template files and then add text, still learning new things. Textboxes should be where textbox is written on screenshot.

Comment: It's very difficult to give you good advice since we have no idea what half the variables are in your code, nor what the content is of the two documents you're "merging" or the purpose behind it. All you can get with this kind of information is "band-aids" rather than good approaches to working with Word...

Comment: Sorry, i will try to explain everything as good as i can. Alle the p variables with numbers are paths to files, 3-4 are for 2 word doc's that i merge into p1, p2 is to save client names in separate file. p3 contains text with small font which you can see over my textboxes, p4 contains image and text below it. Every textbox that i have in my program is just named like you can see on screenshot's

Comment: You can use the [edit] link to add information directly to a question - that's better than using comments... What steps did you use to create the document that looks the way you want it? Because that's what you need to do in your code. Further: can you work with a *template* file that contains all the static text and the graphics - so that all your code needs to do is "fill in the blanks"? If not, why not (so that we understand the starting point)?